# Why can't Fedora start my (hard wired) network?

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, networkmanager, ethernet

**FYI**: I've asked this on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/997853/why-cant-fedora-start-my-hard-wired-network) but not luck so I'm trying here.  I'm not sure which it is more relevant to.

I have a hard-wired Ethernet card/cable to my hub.  I start Fedora 23 but **there's no network**, why?  So I've checked that the card exists:-

```
[root@localhost ~]# lspci | grep Ether
00:0b.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter (rev 10)
[root@localhost ~]# lspci -vm -s 00:0b.0
Device: 00:0b.0
Class:  Ethernet controller
Vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
Device: RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter
SVendor:    Packard Bell B.V.
SDevice:    Device e012
Rev:    10
```

Then I try to start the network (fyi `systemctl restart network.service` has the same output)...

```
[root@localhost ~]# service network start
Starting network (via systemctl):  Job for network.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status network.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

The result of the suggested command (`systemctl status network.service` above) is...

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status network.service
● network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2015-11-08 19:40:26 GMT; 30s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3072 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 08 19:40:23 localhost.localdomain network[3072]: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
Nov 08 19:40:24 localhost.localdomain network[3072]: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
Nov 08 19:40:25 localhost.localdomain network[3072]: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
Nov 08 19:40:25 localhost.localdomain network[3072]: [  OK  ]
Nov 08 19:40:26 localhost.localdomain network[3072]: Bringing up interface enp0s11:  Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.
Nov 08 19:40:26 localhost.localdomain network[3072]: [FAILED]
Nov 08 19:40:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: network.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 08 19:40:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Nov 08 19:40:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: network.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 08 19:40:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: network.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Then I came across some suggestions on here that I check the contents of network-scipts and *ifcfg-enp0s11*, the one that failed above seems to be the one I'm looking for, the MAC address is the same as the one listed in `ifconfig -a` for that named device

```
[root@localhost ~]# more /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s11 
HWADDR=00:13:D4:86:EB:18
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=enp0s11
UUID=b7fce5e7-b3aa-4e95-a014-8661889e9cce
ONBOOT=yes
```

My other options in network-scripts were

```
ifcfg-enp0s11  ifdown-ippp  ifdown-routes    ifup          ifup-ipv6   ifup-ppp       ifup-tunnel
ifcfg-lo       ifdown-ipv6  ifdown-sit       ifup-aliases  ifup-isdn   ifup-routes    ifup-wireless
ifdown         ifdown-isdn  ifdown-Team      ifup-bnep     ifup-plip   ifup-sit       init.ipv6-global
ifdown-bnep    ifdown-post  ifdown-TeamPort  ifup-eth      ifup-plusb  ifup-Team      network-functions
ifdown-eth     ifdown-ppp   ifdown-tunnel    ifup-ippp     ifup-post   ifup-TeamPort  network-functions-ipv6
```

But `ifup eth`, `ifup eth1`, `ifup eth2`, `ifup enp0s11` and `ifup lo` all say there's no config found?!

```
[root@localhost ~]# ifup eth
/usr/sbin/ifup: configuration for eth not found.
Usage: ifup <device name>
```

I partially understand that the `ifup` commands are not really used anymore because of NetworkManager, which is running...

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status NetworkManager.service
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2015-11-08 19:35:13 GMT; 33min ago
 Main PID: 905 (NetworkManager)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           └─905 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Nov 08 19:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[905]: <info>  (virbr0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Nov 08 19:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[905]: <info>  (virbr0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov 08 19:35:35 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[905]: <info>  (virbr0-nic): link disconnected (calling deferred action)
Nov 08 19:36:57 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[905]: <info>  use BlueZ version 5
Nov 08 19:40:31 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[905]: <info>  connectivity: check for uri 'http://fedoraproject.org/static/hotspot.txt' failed with 'Error resolving 'fedoraproject.org': Name or service not known'
Nov 08 19:45:31 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[905]: <info>  connectivity: check for uri 'http://fedoraproject.org/static/hotspot.txt' failed with 'Error resolving 'fedoraproject.org': Name or service not known'
Nov 08 19:50:31 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[905]: <info>  connectivity: check for uri 'http://fedoraproject.org/static/hotspot.txt' failed with 'Error resolving 'fedoraproject.org': Name or service not known'
Nov 08 19:55:31 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[905]: <info>  connectivity: check for uri 'http://fedoraproject.org/static/hotspot.txt' failed with 'Error resolving 'fedoraproject.org': Name or service not known'
Nov 08 20:00:31 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[905]: <info>  connectivity: check for uri 'http://fedoraproject.org/static/hotspot.txt' failed with 'Error resolving 'fedoraproject.org': Name or service not known'
Nov 08 20:05:31 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[905]: <info>  connectivity: check for uri 'http://fedoraproject.org/static/hotspot.txt' failed with 'Error resolving 'fedoraproject.org': Name or service not known'
```

Any ideas why I have no network?

Comment: do you have the realtek firmware somewhere under /lib/firmware?  most realtek nics require firmware files to be 'uploaded' at boot time.  what does  `dmesg` or `/var/log/kern.log` say about the NIC?  maybe `dmesg | grep -iE 'realtek|rtl|e012'` will help.

Comment: what does `ls -l /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo` and `cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo` tell you? (Without loop-back working you can get lots of weird network errors)

Comment: I agree with Dave.  You need to get loopback working first.

Comment: I'll check those tonight

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Same issue with fedora 24. Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: I'm afraid not.  I figured it was a hardware problem and gave up.